# doubt about an integral that concerns a delta dirac

Tags: dirac-delta

I want to calculate the integral

$$F=\int \sum_{m=-\infty}^\infty e^{im(\varphi-\varphi')} \cos(p\varphi') \, d\varphi'$$

In this case I must assume that $m$ and $n$ are integers. As I understand to perform this integral I must transform the cosine function into exponential and then integrate. In this way I obtain that:

$$F=\pi\cos(p\varphi)$$

Is there a problem in what has been done?

Comment: I see an $m$ in that integral, but no $n.$ Might you have meant $m$ and $p$? $\qquad$

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
& \int_0^{2\pi} \sum_{m=-\infty}^\infty e^{im(\varphi-\varphi')} \cos(p\varphi') \, d\varphi' = \int_0^{2\pi} \sum_{m=-\infty}^\infty e^{im(\varphi-\varphi')} \frac 1 2 \left(e^{ip\varphi'} + e^{-ip\varphi'} \right) \, d\varphi' \\[10pt]
= {} & \frac 1 2 \sum_{m=-\infty}^\infty e^{im\varphi} \int_0^{2\pi} \left( e^{-i \varphi'(m-p)} + e^{-i\varphi'(m+p)} \right) \, d\varphi' \tag 1
\end{align}

\begin{align}
& \int_0^{2\pi} e^{-i\varphi'(m-p)} \, d\varphi' = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{when } m\ne p, \\
2\pi & \text{when } m=p. \end{cases} \\[5pt]
& \int_0^{2\pi} e^{-i\varphi'(m+p)} \, d\varphi' = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{when } m\ne -p, \\
2\pi & \text{when } m=-p. \end{cases}
\end{align}

So line $(1)$ above becomes
$$
\frac 1 2 \left( e^{ip\varphi} \cdot 2\pi + e^{-ip\varphi} \cdot 2\pi \right) = 2\pi \cos(p\varphi).
$$

You have $\pi$ where I have $2\pi,$ so the question for both of us now is which if either is right.

The above assumes $p\ne0,$ i.e. $p$ and $-p$ are two different numebers, so one would look at the case $p=0$ separately.